# Can you ask ruby to treat warnings as errors?

Tags: ruby, warnings, heckle

Does ruby allow you to treat warnings as errors?

One reason I'd like to do this is to ensure that if heckle removing a line of code means that a warning occurs, I have the option of ensuring that the mutant get killed.

Comment: I filed a feature request for a command line flag to make warns exceptions... http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3916

Comment: The Doctor What's RFE garnered a response noting that setting $DEBUG = true causes "too many arguments for format string" to be turned from a warning into an Exception.

Comment: @TheDoctorWhat your link is out of date.  New link: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3916

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is unfortunately no real way of doing this, at least not on most versions of Ruby out there (variations *may* exist), **short of monitoring the program output** and aborting it when a warning appears on standard error.  Here's why:

- **Ruby defines [`Kernel.warn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M006017), which you *can* redefine** to do whatever you wish (including exiting), and which you'd *expect* (hope) to be used consistently by Ruby to report warnings (including internal e.g. parsing warning), *but*
- **methods implemented natively** (in C) inside Ruby will in turn directly invoke a native method called `rb_warn` from `source/server.c`, completely **bypassing your redefinition of `Kernel.warn`** (e.g. the "`string literal in condition`" warning, for example, issued when doing something like: `do_something if 'string'`, is printed via the native `rb_warn` from `source/parse.c`)
- to make things even worse, there is an additional, `rb_warning` native method, which can be used by Ruby to log warnings if `-w` or `-v` is specified.

So, if you need to take action solely on warnings generated by your application code's calling `Kernel.warn` then **simply redefine `Kernel.warn`.  Otherwise, you have exactly two options**:

1. alter `source/error.c` to exit in `rb_warn` and `rb_warning` (and `rb_warn_m`?), and rebuild Ruby
2. monitor your program's standard error output for '`: warning:`', and abort it on match

Comment: Thanks. An authoritative answer if ever I saw one!

Comment: To monitor your program's standard error output for ": warning:", http://stackoverflow.com/a/32941696/18096 might be useful.

Answer (score 12):

You can finally do that by overriding `Warning.warn` like

```
module Warning
  def warn(msg)
    raise msg
  end
end
```

This will turn the warning into an exception. This solution works at least since 2.4 branch.

Answer (score 1):

You could also potentially use DTrace, and intercept the calls to `rb_warn` and `rb_warning`, though that's not going to produce exceptions you can rescue from somewhere.  Rather, it'll just put them somewhere you can easily log them.