# Getting stack trace info for a ruby warning

Tags: ruby, utf-8, warnings, stack-trace, ruby-1.9

I've been running into some strange errors with UTF strings in ruby 1.9. Often ruby will complain on something like this:

```
warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
```

I'd like to be able to show a full stack trace on a warning, or apply some kind of monkey patch that i can override the default warning functionality. How would i do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the file and line number be displayed in your warning by default?

Answer (score 2):

If the warning comes from Ruby code(instead of native C), you can overwrite `Warning#warn`, then the warning becomes an exception you will get the backtrace of course:

```
module Warning
  def warn(msg)
    raise msg
  end
end
```

Thanks to: [Can you ask ruby to treat warnings as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660737/can-you-ask-ruby-to-treat-warnings-as-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$DEBUG = true`. That will cause at least some warnings to turn into errors.

Comment: In ruby? Can you elaborate? I'm curious how I'd do that.

Comment: @Thilo How you’d set it? Either `ruby --debug` or just `$DEBUG = true`.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. I'm already in debugging mode. I'd like to do something like a begin/rescue/end for warnings where i can grab a 'warning' object and get a backtrace from it