# Preventing methods from being re-defined

Tags: ruby

So, I need to make a method within a class protected from re-definition. I am not really sure how else to explain it so here's the code:

```
module Foo
    def bar
        p "lol"
    end
end
```

Now, that's the original `Foo#bar` method and I need it to be *like* a constant. So, I did come up with a solution. That was to save the method in a Constant and detect when someone tried changing it it would simply re-load it from that constant (it was a Proc object):

```
module Foo
        Original_bar = Proc.new { p "lol" }

        def bar
            Original_bar.call
        end

        def self.method_added(method_name)
            if method_name == :bar
                def Foo::bar
                    Original_bar.call
                end
            end
        end
end
```

But this isn't completely *safe* since once could use the same "trick" I did to bypass `method_added` and I am not really fond of this, since it's not very ruby-like.

---

### Tests

A normal test:

```
module Foo
    def bar
        p "lmao"
    end
end

Foo::bar # => "lol"
```

And another test using *the trick*:

```
def Foo::bar
    p "rofl"
end

Foo::bar # => "rofl"
```

---

### tl;dr

**How to make a method in Ruby "unredefinable" <del>(if that's even a word)</del>?**

Comment: I think Ruby is an exceptionally bad language to choose for this requirement. Using the `*_eval` and `*_exec` method, it would probably be possible to defeat every kind of "protection" you could apply. What are you trying to achieve, after all?

Comment: You're looking for a ruby equivilent of `final` in Java, from what I can tell.  I don't believe such a thing exists.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark Well, there's basically a way for people to ass their own "extensions" to an application I'm making. I just wouldn't like them shoving their fingers into the `Core` module. I wouldn't mind protecting the module as a whole either. :D

Comment: @Matt: `final` prevents overriding of methods in subclasses. In Ruby, you don't even need to create a child class, you can directly modify the original method.

Comment: @with a dot: As I said, you can't do that in Ruby. It'd be much better if you use OS-provided protection mechanisms like process separation for this OR if you use [sandboxing](http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/781-playing-with-fire-running-uploaded-ruby-code-in-a-sandbox-david-stevenson) (but I wouldn't trust that, either). **EDIT** If your application is written in C or C++ and just uses Ruby as an extension language, you could write the API in C and just make it available in Ruby.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark Well, the person who installs the "extension" should trust the source it comes from, they can also easily un-install it, but still I don't want them fracking things up. I mean, this isn't really a top priority: I could live without it.

Comment: @withadot. In that case I don't think it's worth the effort. Users could easily break your mechanisms if they wanted to, so why even bother?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark [regarding the edit] Nope, pure Ruby. They can optionally create extensions using Javascript through rubyracer

Comment: Is it an option to drop Ruby scripting support completely in favor of Javascript? You could make this pretty secure (users wouldn't even need to trust the extension authors).

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark, well... Yeah, it could be an option... Definitely, actually. I don't mind it. I'm not sure anyone else might.

Comment: Right, so this should be closed or deleted, then? Since There's no answer. Or the answer is simply no. Someone answer it so I can ✓ it.

Comment: @FrederickCheung It has some `@variables` that change. So, nope. But it is a brilliant idea, though.

Comment: Oh well. I moved the @vars to singleton class. SO, that actually got it working for me. You should post this in the answer! :D

Comment: In the second last snippet, `Foo::bar` won't work, because `bar` is an instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you freeze the module that should prevent method being added to it.

Note that a c extension can unfreeze variables (see [evil.rb](http://rubydoc.info/gems/evil-ruby/0.1.0/Object) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code warn you that a method has been over-ridden by turning on warnings:

```
$VERBOSE = true

module Foo
  def self.bar
    p "lmao"
  end
end

def Foo::bar
    p "rofl"
end

(irb):9: warning: method redefined; discarding old bar
```

It may be possible, but not [practical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660737/can-you-ask-ruby-to-treat-warnings-as-errors), to raise an exception when warnings are issued.

This won't warn you if you first undefine Foo.bar, however.