# Capturing warning messages

Tags: ruby, warnings, ruby-1.9.3

Is there a way to capture the warnings, something like rescue for exceptions? I do not want to simply disable the warnings (by doing `$VERBOSE = nil`) but want to capture the content of the warning messages during run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect `stderr` to a StringIO object to capture the warnings output in a string:

```
require 'stringio'

old_stderr = $stderr
$stderr = StringIO.new
Foo = 1
Foo = 2 # generates a warning
puts $stderr.string # prints the warning
$stderr = old_stderr
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'stringio'

def capture_stderr
  old, $stderr = $stderr, StringIO.new
  result = yield
  [result, $stderr.string]
ensure
  $stderr = old
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda ugly because you will be writing to files and you might not have permission to write to them, and it will hide ALL output to `$stderr`, not just the warnings, but it works:

```
$stderr.reopen("errors.txt")
MyConst = 4
MyConst = 5   # generates a warning on the standard error output
$stderr.reopen("errors2.txt")
puts "The following errors happened:"
puts File.read("errors.txt")
```

Comment: Can it be redirected to some Ruby internal IO rather than an external file?