# Thread-safe alternative of global variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use multi-thread Puma as a production server so my code should be thread-safe.
I read that the usage of global variables isn't thread-safe. What is the alternative to global variables in this case?
I used global variables (without value changes) as Redis keys for set/get etc.

```
#initializers/redis.rb

$DRIVER_LOCATIONS = "driver_locations"
```

and in code

```
REDIS.with do |conn|
  conn.geoadd($DRIVER_LOCATIONS, latitude, longitude, id)
end
```

Or there is no need to change something?

Comment: If you're only reading them, then you should be fine. Most/all problems arise when you try to concurrently write to the same place. BTW, why a global var here, and not a constant?

Comment: @anothermh: oh, but you cause total chaos in your app with a single-threaded database. Without a database at all, even.

Comment: @anothermh: I was saying that the single-threaded nature of redis has nothing to do with the amount of corruption/damage that an improperly implemented multi-threaded app can do to itself.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you should probably use a constant there instead of a global variable

```rb
#initializers/redis.rb

DRIVER_LOCATIONS = "driver_locations"

# ...

REDIS.with do |conn|
  conn.geoadd(DRIVER_LOCATIONS, latitude, longitude, id)
end
```

Using the global variable shouldn't be that bad in your use case as it's set during initialization and I'm assuming that it's only done once.

Comment: fyi, constants can be changed see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537564/ruby-constants-seem-to-be-invisibly-alterable