# Ruby how to make exit on warning?

Tags: ruby, warnings, metaprogramming, compiler-warnings

I read that it was possible to make Ruby exit on warning by redefining Kernel.warn, but I have no idea how. How do I make Ruby exit on warn? Please provide working example.

Comment: Note: do not make it check for warnings that may have been generated by/from native code - I just need something that will stop bad Ruby code from running.

Comment: Of possible interest: @vladr's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660737/can-you-ask-ruby-to-treat-warnings-as-errors/662436#662436).

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What have you tried? What happened? What do you think should have happened instead? Do you know how to define a method in Ruby? Because that's pretty much the answer: define a method named `warn` to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to override the `Kernel#warn`

```
module Kernel
    alias orig_warn warn
    def warn args
        orig_warn args
        exit
    end
end

puts "Foo"
warn "Bar"
puts "Don't want to see this"
```